# Can I use auto keyword in a template class object which will know its type dynamically? And can't i use auto keyword without an initializer?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to implement LinkedLists using a class template. I want the program to decide the type of the LinkedList object and the variable x (element to be inserted or deleted) at the time of input. I tried the following code but it gives error in the lines 1 and 2.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class dt>
class LinkedList{
  dt element;
  LinkedList* next; 
public:
  LinkedList():next(NULL){}
  // Basic Linked List Functions and their definitions
};

int main(){
int opt;
auto x;                                   //.....1
LinkedList<auto> LL;                      //.....2

do{
 cout<<"\nEnter the Option number to perform:1--> Push(x)\n2--> Push(x,n)3--> Pop()\n4--> Pop(n)\n5--> Pop(x)\n6--> Exit";
 cin>>opt;
 switch(opt){
     case 1: cout<<"\nEnter x: ";
             cin>>x;
             LL.Push(x); 
             break;
     case 2: cout<<"\nEnter x and n";
             cin>>x>>n;
             LL.Push(x,n);
             break;
     case 3: LL.Pop();
             break;
     case 4: cout<<"\nEnter n";
             cin>>n;
             LL.Pop(n);
             break;
     case 5: cout<<"\nEnter x";
             cin>>x;
             LL.Pop(x);
 }
 LL.Print();             
 }while(opt<5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `x`? You may be thinking that `auto` is a proper type, but it is not. It simply requests that the compiler deduce the appropriate type for you.

Comment: None of that is going to work. `C++` needs to know the types at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the program to decide the type of the LinkedList object and the variable x (element to be inserted or deleted) at the time of input.

That's not possible. In C++, all types must be known at compile time.

```
auto x;
```

is not valid. `auto` can be used to deduce the type at compile only if the variable is initialized at the point of declaration.

```
auto x = 10;    // Type of x is deduced to be int at compile time.
auto y = 10.5;  // Type of y is deduced to be double at compile time.
```

Answer (score 1):

Even with 'auto' c++ is statically typed. That is, auto only prevents the programmer from having to know/decide the variable type, the compiler still has to be able to determine an exact type.

So in a function body an 'auto' variable has to have an initializer, when used as a lambda parameter the compier has to be able to determine a type from the argument passed and when used as a return type the compiler has to be able to treat all return statements as returning the same type.